# Lock browser Current tab URL Bar through Jquery during open the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I need to lock browser current opened tab url bar so any user can not change url from currently opened page.

[For you reference screen shot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUTtZ.png)

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: Every malicious websites wet dream !

Comment: you can only do that in a popup, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this script to open tab in new windpow where user can't change

`window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')`